# Make div wider when viewport get less wide

Tags: viewport, viewport-units

Is it possible to make a DIV (set to width="40%") grow in width as the viewport (browser window) gets less wide?

I know that you can also use the 40vw, instead of 40%,  to make the div scale down when viewport sizes down but I want the div to go wider when the viewport gets narrower.

thanks, Eddy

Comment: You're looking for "media queries", which allows you to apply different css rules based on the viewport size (amongst others)

Comment: Thanks. Needed a few media query steps based on window size but it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can!

There are these tools called media queries which help to re-work elements once a certain resolution or view-port has been reached.

Here is your typical meta-viewport tag. This sets the browser layout viewport relative to the css styling.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Once you got that in..

```
        #div {
            // basic styles
        }

        @media all and (max-width: 600px) {
            #div {
                width: 40%;
                // extra styles for mobile
            }
        }

        @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
            #div {
                width: 60%;
                // extra styles for desktop
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. It took some doing with a number of (min-width) steps but it works well.